# How to bind lambdas for STL algorithms to C style multidimensional arrays?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, lambda, stl-algorithm

I've been trying to use the `STL` algorithms to work with elements of multidimensional arrays, and nothing seems to bind to them. How do I do this:

```
// Declaration of pix:
float pix[1000][2];

// (...)

const int sizeToParse = 300;
static auto colLessThan = [] 
    (const float coordPair_lhs[2], const float coordPair_rhs[2]) -> bool 
    // (const float** coordPair_lhs, const float** coordPair_rhs) -> bool 
    // (const float* coordPair_lhs[], const float* coordPair_rhs[]) -> bool 
{
    return coordPair_lhs[1] < coordPair_rhs[1]; 
};
float** lhsColMinIt;
float** lhsColMaxIt;
// float* lhsColMinIt[2];
// float* lhsColMaxIt[2];
std::tie(lhsColMinIt, lhsColMaxIt) = std::minmax_element(pix, pix + sizeToParse, colLessThan);
```

All of my attempts are rejected with a compiler error.

After the accepted answer it got reduced to this:

> In instantiation of ‘std::tuple<_T1, _T2>& std::tuple<_T1,
>   _T2>::operator=(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&) [with _U1 = const float (*)[2]; _U2 = const float (*)[2]; _T1 = float (*&)[2]; _T2 = float (*&)[2]]’:src/ClusterPairFunctions.cc:32:109:   required from here
>   /data/hunyadi/usr/include/c++/7.1.0/tuple:1252:25: error: invalid
>   conversion from ‘const float (*) [2]’ to ‘float (*)[2]’ [-fpermissive]

**Update:**
Using the method provided by the accepted answer, the code works, I just failed to demangle that the compiler was reporting const incorrectness inside `std::tuple`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem you have with the code you show? Doesn't it build? Do you get crashes? Unexpected results? Something else?

Comment: Also, please, post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to give the chance to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Without knowing anything more (since you don't *show* us the compiler error) I guess it has something to do with a mismatch of types. The arguments to the lambda are *pointers* to `float` (i.e. `float*`), but the elements of the array `pix` are *arrays* of two `float`, i.e. type `float[2]`. The solution is shown in [the answer from Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44824958/440558).

Comment: Another problem (also solved by [the answer from Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44824958/440558)) is that a pointer to a pointer to some type is *not* the same as an array of arrays of the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++14, use `const auto&` in the lambda.

If you have to provide type explicitly:

```
static auto colLessThan = [] (const float (&lhs)[2], const float (&rhs)[2])
{
    return lhs[1] < rhs[1];
};

float (*lhsColMinIt)[2];
float (*lhsColMaxIt)[2];
std::tie(lhsColMinIt, lhsColMaxIt) =
    std::minmax_element(pix, pix + sizeToParse, colLessThan);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8e728a32860bd1d)

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a little on the changes you made, and *why* you made them?

Comment: I confirmed that this indeed works, my code still refuses to compile with it :(